# "Access forbidden!" apache + wsgi + xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I am banging my head against a brick wall here. I have a Apache 2.4 server via xampp which I am trying to set up with a wsgi app. I followed the instruction at https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html  and have searched the web a lot but nothing seems to be working and i am always getting this error

```
Access forbidden!

    You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

    10.226.65.62
    Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j mod_wsgi/4.4.12 Python/2.7.12 PHP/5.6.24
```

I have set window folder permission to 'Everyone' and tried various combinations of

```
<Directory "C:/wsgi-scripts">
   AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

but nothing seems to work. Anyone have any ideas on this? my httpd.conf can be found here http://pastebin.com/uLtdXqrv

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You told Apache to forbid access. You have:

```
<Directory "C:/wsgi-scripts">
   AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

it should be:

```
<Directory "C:/wsgi-scripts">
   AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Have a look at the Apache documentation to understand the difference between `denied` and `granted`.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Comment: Thanks Graham, I changed that and restarted apache  with no change in behavior... any thoughts?

Comment: Try commenting out the line ``Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf``. The ``VirtualHost`` in that file is possibly overriding it. That or add the mod_wsgi configuration inside the default ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: Thanks again @graham. I commented out that line but still the same message.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to the issue but after reading (your??) comments on Running mod_wsgi on windows I replaced the default VC11 Xampp Apache 2.4 with VC9 Apache from 'apache haus' and copied the *.conf files across. Apart from that everything else is default Xampp, and the app i am trying to run is the one from https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html